# Make children of flex div have same height (on per-"row" basis)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex div (`.parent`) with child divs (you guessed it, `.child`) that wraps into more rows. My problem is that I can't seem to get the border of each div `.card` to have the same height without ruining my "grid". When I try designating a specific height for `.child`, etc. the heights look terrible because not each row has the same lengths of content. I've seen examples of this but am not sure how to tackle it with flex so that the multiple rows have the same height (without every single "cell" being the same height and producing as much of a mess.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.a-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}

.child .card {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* height: 600px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>

      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trying to avoid what's going on here (current code example): https://jsfiddle.net/4gy7fzw1/

Example of code without set heights: https://jsfiddle.net/t2yzfkm9/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, to have each column in a flexbox layout have the same height, all you need to do is specify `display: flex` on the parent element (`.parent`). In your specific situation, you're setting `height: 100%` on the child element (`.child`).

In flexbox, `height: 100%` actually does the **opposite** of what you may expect, due to percentage-driven values being based on the height of the containing block. `height: auto` will allow the element to expand (and is the default).

In short, to have your columns be equal height, simply **remove** `height: 100%` from `.child`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.a-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}

.child .card {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* height: 600px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>

      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: deleted my last comment—I wasn't applying `flex` to the actual parent locally. It seems to have worked! I appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

width and height don't work with flex, use "flex" property to give/set width of the elements.

I have updated your css for "child" and "parent" class to make all the cards same in height.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 
}

.child {
  margin: 1%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.a-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}

.child .card {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* height: 600px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>

      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="card">

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/D1p6UX3.jpg" width="240" height="240"><br>
      <p class="a-title">
        Title
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        Some example text that I'm too lazy to ipsum right now.
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Some fake link</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```